# Setting SASL callback handler in Docker kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, sasl

I am trying to implement a custom server login callback handler in my Dockerized Kafka cluster. The property in the properties file is relatively simple to set through Docker:

`KAFKA_SASL_SERVER_CALLBACK_HANDLER_CLASS=[full_class_name]`

Additionally then I set up the classpath:

`CLASSPATH=/etc/kafka/jars/*`

and finally map the volume to a location where the .jar file will be:

`-v /my/local/location:/etc/kafka`

But according to the documentation and oAuth examples, in order to set such a property the property name must be prefixed with both the listener name, and the SASL mechanism:

listener.name.*listener_name*.*sasl_mechanism*.sasl.callback.handler.class=

as such with my OUTSIDE listener and PLAIN sasl mechanism, it should be:

`listener.name.outside.plain.sasl.callback.handler.class=`

How do you set this in a docker run / compose? i don't see how i can create an environment variable that will do the job since the basic sasl.callback.handler.class doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insanely the environment variable

`KAFKA_LISTENER_NAME_OUTSIDE_PLAIN_SASL_CALLBACK_HANDLER_CLASS=` actually works, it appears in the server.properties as expected:

listener.name.outside.plain.sasl.callback.handler.class=

Comment: Can you let me know how you came to know about entries in server properties translated by docker.. I am unable to find this call back handler class